# Graph Part of a line

Tags: definite-integrals, graphing-functions

The formula and graph below get close to what I want. This integral shows the AREA of 0.1 to 0.7 in this formula, but I only want the line SEGMENT from 0.1 to 0.7
How do I do that?

Formula:$$ \int _{0.1}^{0.7}\frac{x}{1-x}dx$$

[Integral of a formula graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Bmj.png)

Comment: It is unclear as to what you're asking, do you want to compute the length of the curve from $0.1$ to $0.7$?

Comment: What “segment”? And what about it do you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the area between  $$y=\frac{x}{1-x}$$ graph, the $x=0.1$ line, the $x=0.7$ line and the x axis:

Let $$P=\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\frac{x}{1-x}dx$$
Now substitute: $t=1-x \Rightarrow x=1-t \Rightarrow dt=\frac{dt}{dx}dx=-dx \Rightarrow dx=-dt$
$$P=\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\frac{1-t}{t}\cdot (-dt)=-\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\frac{1-t}{t}dt=-(\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\frac{1}{t}dt-\int_{0.1}^{0.7}dt)=[-(ln(t)-t)+C]_{0.1}^{0.7}=[t-ln(t)+C]_{0.1}^{0.7} $$
Now let's undo substitution:
$$P = [1-x-ln(1-x)+C]_{0.1}^{0.7} =1-0.7-ln(0.3)-1+0.1+ln(0.9)=ln(0.9)-ln(0.3)-0.6 \approx 0.49861228866$$

If you want to calculate the curve length from $x=0.1$ to $x=0.7$ then you should compute $L=\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$
We know that $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$, therefore $dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\frac{d \frac{x}{1-x}}{dx}dx=\frac{d \text{  }x \cdot (\frac{1}{x} \circ (1-x))}{dx}dx=(\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}\cdot(-1)\cdot x + \frac{1}{1-x})dx=(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{1-x})dx=\frac{x+1-x}{(1-x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}dx$
Therefore:
$$L=\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\sqrt{(dx)^2+(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}dx)^2}=\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}}dx \approx 2.332071129605535$$

Answer (score 1):

To make life easier
$$\frac x {1-x}=\frac{x-1+1}{1-x}=-1+\frac1{1-x}$$

$$\int_a^b\frac x {1-x}\,dx=-\int_a^b dx+\int_a^b\frac {dx}{1-x}= ???$$

Comment: Good point! I'm wondering what is the reason somebody has downvoted our answers...

Comment: @Amad I downvoted them. I do watch the tag partial-functions, I got an email for this question, and I don't see what it has to do with that tag. I also don't see what it has to do with the tag graphing-functions, it is unclear to me what this question is asking, and it is unclear to me how this answer is supposed to answer that question. The comments below the question indicate that I am not the only one confused by this question.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel yes, I totally agree with you that the question is asked in a vague way, however we can assume the author wants either to calculate the area between the graph of $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$, the $x=0.1$ line, the $x=0.7$ line and the x axis or compute the length of the $y=\frac{x}{1-x}$ curve for $x \in [0.1; 0.7]$. Therefore, providing solutions to both of possible problems guarantees that one of them is an answer the asker wanted to get. Also simplifying $\frac{x}{1-x}$ to $-1+\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a neat trick on a way to solve both problems. It's just trying to help the asker.